# what is the maximum size of dynamic memory that could be allocated by using C++ in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, memory

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class rmq
{
public:
    rmq() = default;
    rmq(size_t size) :m_pData(new unsigned int[size]), m_size(size) {}
    ~rmq(){   if (m_pData)delete[]m_pData;}
    void populateValue() {
        if (m_pData) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++) m_pData[i] = i;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "NUll reference" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    unsigned int minQuery(size_t firstIdx, size_t lastIdx) {
        unsigned int minValue = 0;
        if (firstIdx < lastIdx && lastIdx <= m_size) {
            minValue = m_pData[firstIdx];
            while (++firstIdx < lastIdx) {
                if (minValue > m_pData[firstIdx]) minValue = m_pData[firstIdx];
            }            
        }
        return minValue;
    }
private:
    unsigned int *m_pData;
    size_t m_size;
};
int main()
{
    rmq r(UINT32_MAX);
    r.populateValue();

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int minvalue = r.minQuery(0, UINT32_MAX);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << "RMQ:" << minvalue <<" "<<"Duration_i`enter code here`n_ns:"<<duration<<std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

When the size is specified as UINT32_MAX I am getting the following exception

Unhandled exception at 0x763BC54F in RMQ.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_array_new_length at memory location 0x004CFAC0.

But the same thing works with UINT16_MAX. Could not comprehend the logic behind the same.

Compiler version is Visual C++ 2015 (also known as Visual C++ 14.0).

Target architecture: x86

Comment: Maximum size of available memory depends on: whether you are compiling as x64, and the available RAM on your machine.

Comment: Please, can we have a [mcve]? We don't need to see your `rmq` class to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You do know that `UINT16_MAX` is `65535`, while `UINT32_MAX` is a little over four billion? Quite a big difference between them.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: The available address space hardly ever depends on the amount of RAM. You should think of RAM as a performance optimization.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I forgot that Virtual Memory (a.k.a. swapping) is a thing. But, in the most common use-case: the amount of RAM one has = the amount of working memory available to the software.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Nonsense. RAM is hardly **ever** a limiting factor. You'd have to have a very exotic system, with very exotic configuration for RAM to limit the memory an application can allocate. Please read [Memory Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366779.aspx).

Comment: From what I recall with Windows XP 32 bit mode, with 4GB of ram, user virtual address space is 2GB, and the maximum single allocation is usually somewhere between 1.0 GB and 1.5 GB, (depending on fragmentation). For Windows XP 32 bit, there is an option to increase user virtual address space to 3GB, but it can slow a system down. I haven't tried it. I don't know if there are similar limits for later versions of 32 bit Windows.

Comment: @rcgldr: The amount of RAM has **no** impact on the amount of virtual address space allotted to a process. By default, a 32-bit version of Windows grants 2GB of address space to a user-mode process (the other 2GB are reserved for the kernel). The user-mode address space is further reduced by the I/O ranges reserved for communication with hardware devices. The lion share goes to the GPU, usually around 0.5GB. This is all unrelated to this question. The OP has run into a limit imposed by their implementation of C++ on the size of a single allocation.

Comment: @rcgldr: No. The amount of RAM has **no** impact. It's not like a contiguous block of address space needs to map to a contiguous block of backing store, be it RAM or the swap file. A contiguous block of address space can be scattered across non-contiguous regions of RAM and the swap file.

Comment: Note there is a difference between Windows and Linux here (at least the last time I tested it), Linux lets you allocate as much memory as will fit into your processes address space and only allocates pages as you put values into that memory. Windows immediately allocates pages for all the memory you requested so will not allow you to allocate more memory than you have available RAM and swap space.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I know that? That's why I stated that it's the case in the most common use case? For instance, I have never seen, the default setting, for Virtual Memory, in Windows, be larger than the RAM itself. Since majority of the users don't bother about changing that setting - it is most common use case.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: So even then the amount of memory controlled by the OS would be size of RAM **plus** size of swap file. Stating that available memory would depend on RAM is very misleading. It's a system setting after all, that limits the total amount of virtual memory. There are so many other factors that impact the amount of memory available to a process, that singling out RAM (hardly even tangentially involved) is just wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable.Could you summarize your points?

Comment: Please update your question first. Things that need to be changed: Show a [mcve]. Provide details about your compiler (vendor, version). Provide details about the target architecture (x86 vs. x64 vs. ARM vs. ARM64).

Comment: Thank you for the info.I have added the details to the question.

Comment: While that is probably sufficient, please *do* provide a [mcve]. Even though the link explains this, it is hard to get through: A MCVE needs to be **minimal**, too. We don't care about the class, or the timing code. A simple one-liner, or 2 at most, suffices to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.I got your vision:-)

Comment: @rcgldr: This question is about a user-mode process, where available RAM has **no** impact on the amount of memory a process can request. And there is no requirement, that the swap file be large enough to store the entire physical memory either. Where did you get that idea from? Kernel-mode has different rules, and different limits.

Comment: @rcgldr: The very first sentence from that page: *"A page file (also known as a "paging file") is an **optional**, hidden system file on a hard disk."* In other words: The swap file can have a size of 0. 0 is clearly smaller than the size of physical memory in any machine. If you're in a hole, stop digging.

Comment: @rcgldr: Programs are allowed to run out of memory, irrespective of the size of the page file. A page file with size 0 may or may not limit the maximum single allocation size. Can we let this rest now? This question has been answered. And it should be clear, that the amount of physical memory has no direct impact on the amount of memory a process can allocate.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to allocate an array of integers with 2^32 elements. This requires 16 GiB of memory.

In a 32-bit address space the maximum total amount of memory available is 4GiB. In windows the most you can allocate to a 32-bit process is 3GiB in 32-bit windows or 4GiB in 64-bit windows. This rises to 8TiB+ for 64-bit processes.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that allocation may still fail even if you are under these limits if your total available RAM and swap space aren't big enough.

Comment: Note, that the exception in question is raised before any attempt to allocate memory is done. The core issue isn't about insufficient memory resources. It is instead caused by running into data type constraints, failing to hold a byte count large enough to represent the requested storage size. While content in this answer isn't wrong, it doesn't address the question that was asked either.

Answer (score 2):

A [std::bad_array_new_length](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_array_new_length) exception is thrown under one of the following conditions:

> 1. array length is negative
> 2. total size of the new array would exceed implementation-defined maximum value
> 3. the number of initializer-clauses exceeds the number of elements to initialize

Your code has hit the second bullet point, when trying to execute the expression `new unsigned int[UINT32_MAX]`. This tries to allocate an array of `unsigned int`s with 2^32 - 1 elements. The size of an `unsigned int` in Visual Studio is 4, so the total size of the array, in bytes, is 4 * (2^32 - 1). That size cannot be represented using a [std::size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t), and consequently cannot be passed to [std::malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) (which `operator new` eventually calls, in Visual Studio's implementation), so the implementation bails out with an exception.

If you need to allocate an array with 2^32 - 1 `unsigned int`s, you will have to compile for a 64-bit target. The largest array of `unsigned int`s you can request for a 32-bit target without getting a `std::bad_array_new_length` would be `unsigned int[UINT32_MAX >> 2]`. Mind you, that will still give you a [std::bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception.

Allocating an array of `unsigned int`s with `UINT16_MAX` elements amounts to 4 * (2^16 - 1) bytes, roughly 256kB. Not entirely a spectacular amount of memory to allocate, so the request is (usually) serviced without an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer.I tried with x64 and found it to be working.And understood the logic behind it.